# JavaScript DropDown Default Selection should trigger onchange Intrexx

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, onchange, intrexx

I am building a small calculater which includes a dropdown which fills some values. Now I am trying to do a default value which also fills these values , but the trigger on that is onchange. Obviously that doesnt work since if its default already it doesnt change on that sense. Now  I tried to do the first entry empty and use a hidden button which changes the selected item to the first one from the list

```
function standartAuswählen(){
var dropdown = getElement("78ABCFFDE76405DDB0C081AC1D6A7C58054F012B"); /*Name Stückzahlgrenze  dropdowncontrol*/
dropdown.options[1].selected = true;
 return true}
```

Now its working to change the selection to the first entry but its doesnt trigger the onchange to fill the values which the dropdown is supposed to fill.
Is there another way to select the first Entry  beside

```
dropdown.options[1].selected = true;
```

which acctually triggers onchange  or another way to make the default values fill other values.

So basically I try to fill values with onchange by a default selection of a dropdown

Comment: getElement.... by what ?

Comment: The getElemnent is from Intrexx. Its basically the Dropdown which is the selected there. And i can acess the Dropdown by the variable "Dropdown".

Comment: What s your onchange code ? Post more please

Comment: The Thing is there isnt  much more Code since Intrexx is like a sandbox tool which creates the Elements , much more i can say about it is that the Drop Down fills 2 other value fields with numbers as soon as the Dropdown changes (on Change). The numbers are pre-Set and connected to the names you can select by the Dropdown (i.E if you choose "test1" the fields are filled with 30 and 50 or if you choose "test2" on the drop down the fi1eld are filled with 10 and 20 or something like that). But it just fills the value fields with numbers on Change but they doesnt fill if i say test1 is the default

Answer (score 0):

I'Ve got a soluction to my problem. I just used the .onchange() on the Dropdown so it uses the onchange Event on the Dropdown.